# trying to find files with special characters in them

Tags: linux, character-encoding, grep

So I have a website that has some pages containing strings like this:

> this is a â€œquoteâ€

I think those are curly double quotes. ie. “ ”.

I'm trying to find all the pages with those characters in them but am having some difficulty. Here's what I've tried:

```
grep -r "\xE2\x80\x9C" .
grep -r "\0342\0200\0234" .
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-P` option worked. eg.

```
grep -r -P "\xE2\x80\x9C" .
```

Is it just not possible without the `-P` option?